# Storing a result set in a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for a way to store a result set in my SQL Server database so it's faster to retrieve, if possible. The reason I want to do this is that I need the information quite frequently, but the data rarely changes so I believe it will improve my database performance a lot.

The only thing I was able to find was `indexed views`, which doesn't work for me since my query doesn't qualify for that kind of view.

My result set is derived from several sql queries, that will increase in time.

My backup solution is to have the program using the database to store it's own copy, so I can skip calling the database. But this will make my system more complex. I would rather have all my data calls in the database so it's easier to keep track of things.

Do any of you know a way store result sets on a SQL Server database?

Comment: Why doesn't it qualify for a view?

Comment: what language is this solution in? ASP.Net, PHP?

Comment: You could look into setting up a Data Warehouse or you could post your query and perhaps we can help you make it perform better.

Comment: ASP .NET - The queries are doing subqueries and other stuff. According to MSDN, it's not allowed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933148(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: Reporting table, with an sp to fill in / update it on some sort of schedule / trigger is the usual way. It's simple, flexible and it works. No point in going madly clever with this sort of thing, you'll lose all the benefit of having it in teh first place.

Comment: @AdrianIftode - Probably because a lot of questions are left open. How fast is the query now? Isn't there any further optimization possible on the query? How many data is being handled? Is it running on decent hardware? In the end, I do believe that instead of downvoting a new user so rapidly, we as a community should try to educate them in how to ask questions.

Comment: I didn't took in information as query time because currently in runs in milliseconds due to a very small database. But thinking into the future I see this query as a potential bottleneck, that I wanted to resolve now. I also didn't display my query since i didn't found it important to the nature of the question.

Comment: @evilfish: How far in the future do you expect performance to become an issue? If the answer is "days", then you are right to be concerned about it, but if the answer is "years" then it should probably be shelved for now.

Comment: @evilfish - Planning for the future is one thing but make sure you don't fall into the trap of *premature optimization*.

Comment: @Lieven Thanks for the warning. I do believe I need to be concerned here though. It might not be as bad as I tell it, but it does not harm to have a plan for potential problems.

Answer (score 2):

> I need the information quite frequently, but the data rarely changes

If the data is going to rarely change, then why not just use a SSI file based on the data in the database. You can always recreate this text file whenever the data changes.

When I did web stuff we served up all the data for all the web pages directly from database queries. We decided to change our model to use SSI files for all the database items that rarely changed. We built a "File Recreation" routine inside the backend admin that would automatically build and overwrite the SSI file when ever the customer changed one of those "rarely" changed database items.

This boosted performance on our servers, cut down on server round trips and spead up the display time. Truly a win-win.